# How to create an invoice and invoice lines via code - Odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to create an invoice and invoice lines via python code.

Here is the code.

```
def createInvoice(self, date_ref):

    // Skipped some code here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    invoice_values = contract._prepare_invoice(date_ref)
          for line in contract_lines:
              invoice_values.setdefault('invoice_line_ids', [])
              invoice_line_values = line._prepare_invoice_line(
                  invoice_id=False
              )
              if invoice_line_values:
                  invoice_values['invoice_line_ids'].append(
                      (0, 0, invoice_line_values)
                  )

          invoices_values.append(invoice_values)
```

​

Values for

```
  invoice_values = {'type': 'in_invoice', 'journal_id': 2, 'company_id': 1, 'line_ids': [(6, 0, [])],

               'partner_id': 42, 'commercial_partner_id': 42, 'fiscal_position_id': False, 

               'invoice_payment_term_id': False, 'invoice_line_ids': [(6, 0, [])], 

               'invoice_partner_bank_id': False, 'invoice_cash_rounding_id': False, 

               'bank_partner_id': 42, 'currency_id': 130, 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2020, 11, 11), 

           'invoice_origin': 'Vendor COntract #1', 'user_id': 2, 'old_contract_id': 6}

 invoice_line_values = {'move_id': False, 'journal_id': False, 'company_id': False, 

                   'account_id': False, 'name': '[E-COM07] Large Cabinet', 'quantity': 1.0, 

                   'price_unit': 1444.01, 'discount': 0.0, 'partner_id': False, 

                   'product_uom_id': 1, 'product_id': 17, 'payment_id': False, 

                   'tax_ids': [(6, 0, [])], 'analytic_line_ids': [(6, 0, [])], 

                   'display_type': False, 'contract_line_id': 7, 'asset_id': False, 

                    'analytic_account_id': False}
```

In create function of account move

```
  vals = {'date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 11), 'type': 'in_invoice', 'journal_id': 2, 

        'company_id': 1, 'currency_id': 130, 'line_ids': [(6, 0, [])], 'partner_id': 42, 

        'commercial_partner_id': 42, 'fiscal_position_id': False, 'user_id': 2, 

        'invoice_date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 11), 'invoice_origin': 'Vendor COntract #1', 

        'invoice_payment_term_id': False, 

        'invoice_line_ids': [(6, 0, []), (0, 0, {'journal_id': False, 'company_id': False, 

        'account_id': 109, 'name': '[E-COM07] Large Cabinet', 'quantity': 1.0, 'price_unit': 1444.01,

        'discount': 0.0, 'partner_id': False, 'product_uom_id': 1, 'product_id': 17, 

        'payment_id': False, 'tax_ids': [(6, 0, [19])], 'analytic_line_ids': [(6, 0, [])], 

        'analytic_account_id': False, 'display_type': False, 'exclude_from_invoice_tab': False, 

       'contract_line_id': 7, 'asset_id': False}), (0, 0, {'journal_id': False, 

       'company_id': False, 'account_id': 109, 'name': '[E-COM09] Large Desk', 'quantity': 1.0, 

       'price_unit': 8118.04, 'discount': 0.0, 'partner_id': False, 'product_uom_id': 1,

       'product_id': 19, 'payment_id': False, 'tax_ids': [(6, 0, [19])],

       'analytic_line_ids': [(6, 0, [])], 'analytic_account_id': False, 'display_type': False, 

       'exclude_from_invoice_tab': False, 'contract_line_id': 8, 'asset_id': False})],

       'invoice_partner_bank_id': False, 'invoice_cash_rounding_id': False, 'bank_partner_id': 42,

       'old_contract_id': 6}
```

It creates the account_move(Invoice) but not the account_move_line(Invoice lines).

What am i missing here?

Comment: `invoice_line_values = {'move_id': False,...}`
Why `move_id` is False

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution,

```
 'line_ids': [(6, 0, [])],
```

The above line caused the problem. I removed it from the `invoice_values` then it worked.